# Story of a robot suspected of murder on a small planet (possibly Asimov)

Tags: story-identification, isaac-asimov, laws-of-robotics

Trying to identify a story of a robot suspected of murder on a fairly small planet.

The planet was initially uninhabited. The robot suspect and the man killed were part of the same visiting expedition.

Investigators have strong suspicions on the robot but also reservations since robot is not supposed to harm people(ala Asimov's 3 Laws of Robotics).

The solution turns out that the man had shot himself (by accident) by discharging his weapon and the bullet having traveled around the planet hitting him.

There was also the explanation for the robot's reluctance to be completely truthful to the investigators based on Laws of Robotics.

I imagine the author could be Asimov himself. (EDIT: I've gone over descriptions of his robot stories and no match could be found).

EDIT2: There might have been a romantic/jealousy angle to the story as there were two+ more astronauts (male/female) in the expedition. They were suspects too but robot was the most likely(if not for the Law of Robotics).

I read it in 1980s Soviet sci-fi magazine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no such story by Asimov. Unless it's one of his later "humorous" stories.

Comment: The story was pretty serious, a murder mystery in a sci-fi setting. There was  a plausible sounding explanation of bullet's travel. So not Asimov but an admirer of his.

Comment: I'm sure I've heard of this before, iirc in another story about a rock being thrown around a planet to kill someone or something like that.  Damned if I can remember the story though.. :/

Comment: There's an old ?Ben Bova? story about early US and USSR astronauts fighting a gun battle on the moon, then having to cooperate because the bullets go into orbit.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Men of Good Will; https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v22n05_1964-06_modified/Galaxy_v22n05_1964-06_modified_djvu.txt

Comment: "Throw X around a planet to hit something" - there's a scene like that in Raft by Stephen Baxter. Specifically, it's a spear thrown around the world by a hunter, who then catches it again when it orbits by him a few seconds later. Planets are extremely small in this universe, due to gravitational constants being thousands of times stronger than other forces - i.e., people can feel the gravitational pull of nearby people.

Comment: Do you remember that sci-fi magazine?

Comment: It might be the non-canon story of _Caliban_.