# Short story about an astronaut being shot by his own bullet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I’m looking for a short story which involved an astronaut who was on the moon and fired a gun which caused the bullet to orbit and hit him on its return.  I read this in the earlyish 50s.

Comment: Possibly ["Men of Good Will"](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v22n05_1964-06_modified/Galaxy_v22n05_1964-06_modified_djvu.txt) by Poul Andersen.  Two moon bases dealing the effects of high power rifle shots on the Earth's moon.

Comment: That story is by Ben Bova, not Poul Anderson.  It is the one I thought of first as well.

Comment: Is it the same story as asked about in [Story of a robot suspected of murder on a small planet (possibly Asimov)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173585/story-of-a-robot-suspected-of-murder-on-a-small-planet-possibly-asimov)?

Comment: Oops.  Read the wrong line while checking the author.  Ben Bova it is.

Comment: @JRE To be fair, Poul Anderson did write something similar. "Holmgang" (originally titled "Out of the Iron Womb"). At the climax, two men agree to have a duel with heavy wrenches as hand weapons on the surface of a small asteroid. The bad guy cheats by bringing a gun to the party. The good guy then uses an air tank from his spacesuit to act as a rocket so he can fly in low orbit *clear around* the asteroid and blindside the bad guy by hitting him from behind.

Answer (score 17):

I just read a story in the March 1928 issue of *Amazing Stories* in which that happens.  It's called "Sub-Satellite," by Charles Cloukey (available to read online [here](http://freeread.com.au/@RGLibrary/CharlesCloukey/Stories/SubSatellite.html)).

> In the hour of his triumph, Duseau had been killed. Consider the
>   tremendous power of the Marvite gun. Long ago men calculated that a
>   bullet shot from a gun with a muzzle velocity of 6,500 feet a second
>   would, if there were no obstacles in its path, completely encircle the
>   moon! And that is what happened! **One of the bullets Duseau shot from
>   the summit of "Mount Olympus" traveled all the way around the moon,
>   and hit him in the back!** And that, Kornfield, is what I was thinking
>   about when I spoke of a sub-satellite.

Of course, it immediately reminded me of Bova's story, "Men of "Good Will," but this was probably forty years before Bova.

Comment: Wow, nice find!

Comment: That story was reprinted in a 1967 issue of *Amazing Stories* but that doesn't help to explain how the OP happened to read it "in the earlyish 50s". My guess is, this idea has been used more than once. http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54846