# Shooting bullet around the Moon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the 1980s, most likely in Analog SF magazine, though could have been an anthology, I read a story which included a gun standoff on the Moon. One of the characters shot his gun (Colt 45?), but his bullet orbited the Moon, coming back around and hitting his opponent (at least that is how I recall the story). I'd like to take another look at that story, if anyone can give me a lead to its title, author and place of publication.

Comment: 1980s sounds late for a story like this, at least set on the Moon, since it was known by the 1960s that the Moon's gravity field (due to irregular distributions of masscons) is "lumpy" and it's almost impossible to find a stable low-altitude orbit.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [Short story about an astronaut being shot by his own bullet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/210968/20774)

Comment: Note that there was a 1928 story called "Sub-satellite" published in *Amazing*, as detailed in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/227878/101407), where an astronaut on the Moon is shot by _his own_ bullet.  It was reprinted in *Amazing* in the late 1960s.

Comment: Also possible match in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254790/u-s-lunar-base-subjected-to-periodic-bombardment-by-an-orbiting-cloud-of-bullet?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, I remember reading Sub-Satellite years ago, but isn't the story I'm seeking. I now realize that I was also mixing up elements of this story with another one as well.  That story was the one that featured an “old Army .45” (which I always assumed was a Model 1911 Colt semi-automatic pistol that was standard U.S. Army issue from the First World War through about 1980).  In that story, the pistol had been smuggled on board a space craft and was used as a surprise weapon to defeat a “bad guy” type character.  It was referred to in that story as an antique, or collector’s piece.

Comment: (Nitpick: I think you mean that one of the characters _fired_ his gun.  If he had _shot_ it, he'd have fired a bullet into it from a second gun or similar.  — Sorry, can't help myself.)